# MapSide Join in MR Jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using MapSide join inorder to get 2 different files in my MR jobs.

```
Input File 1:
0,5.3
26,4.9
54,4.9
.
.
.

InputFile 2:
0   Anju,,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3
26  Remya,,3.3,EEE,B,1.6,0.3
54  akhila,,3.3,IT,C,1.3,0.3
```

My intension is to Replace  as below

```
Anju,5.3,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3
Remya,4.9,3.3,EEE,B,1.6,0.3
akhila,4.9,3.3,IT,C,1.3,0.3
```

What I did is

Inorder to get 2 files as input I used 2 mappers(`MultipleInput`).

The first column of 2 files is the file offset.

In 1 st map I emitted first col as key(Logwritable offset) and rest as value of 1 st file
In 2 st map also I emitted first col as key(Logwritable offset) and rest as value of 2 nd file

So in reducer I am able to get

```
Reducer
key 0
value 5.3
value Anju,S,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3

Reducer
key 26
value Remya,,3.3,EEE,B,1.6,0.3
value 4.9

Reducer
key 54
value 4.9
value akhila,,3.3,IT,C,1.3,0.3
```

How will I `replace` value any idea?

Whether my approach is right or should I follow any alterbative way?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a replacement with this code:

```
String result = null;
String replacement = null;
for (Text value: values) {
    String valueStr = value.toString();
    if (valueStr.contains(",,")) {
        result = valueStr;
    } else {
        replacement = valueStr;
    }
}
if (result == null || replacement == null) {
    return;
}
result = result.replaceFirst(",,", "," + replacement + ",");
// write result
```

But it is not MapSide join. To do MapSide join you should read file with replacements (`InputFile 1`) in every mapper (in setup phase) and then join this data with `InputFile 2` in map phase. Example:

```
private Map < Integer, Double > replacements;

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    replacements = new HashMap < Integer, Double > ();
    // read FileInput 1 to replacements
    // ...
}

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] parts = value.toString().split("\t"); // 0   Anju,,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    if (!replacements.containsKey(id)) {
        return; // can't replace
    }
    Double replacement = replacements.get(id);
    String result = parts[1].replaceFirst(",,", "," + replacement + ",");
    // write result to context
}
```

Comment: Yes that is right.But my 2 files are of large volumn.and holding those values in replacements may end up in large memory useage.and may lead to heapspace